# python: replacement replace wrong place of the line

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace

I have original line:
2.48724e-008 0.00022974 0.65 1 4 0 0 0.0002 2 2 2 0
I want new line:
6.1054382342e-10 1.26357e-05 0.65 1 4 0 0 1.1e-05 2 2 2 0

Code:

```
replacement = {'2.48724e-008':'6.1054382342e-10','0.00022974':'1.26357e-05','0.0002':'1.1e-05')}
for src, target in replacement.iteritems():
      line = line.replace(src,target)
```

But result was:
6.1054382342e-10 1.1e-052974 0.65 1 4 0 0 1.1e-05 2 2 2 0

The second number is wrong. Seems like python found the '0.0002' in the original line and replace it with '1.1e-05' no matter what is after it.

Would you please help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

The problem comes from the fact that with a `dict`, the keys can appear in any order.  An iterable (tuple or list) would suffice for what you do

```
replacement = (
  ('2.48724e-008','6.1054382342e-10'),
  ('0.00022974','1.26357e-05'),
  ('0.0002','1.1e-05')
)   
for src, target in replacement:
  line = line.replace(src,target)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just sort the keys first:

```
replacement = {'2.48724e-008':'6.1054382342e-10','0.00022974':'1.26357e-05','0.0002':'1.1e-05')}
for src, target in sorted(replacement.items(), reverse=True):
    line = line.replace(src,target)
```

Comment: `for src, target in sorted(replacement.viewitems(), reverse=True):` would remove the need for a lookup in each iteration. The keys are unique anyway, so it will never compare the values regardless. In Py3, it would just be `.items()`, not `.viewitems()`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Thanks a lot; I was wondering if something like that could be done.  I should have thought of that.  You can do `.items()` in Py2 also, so that's what I put in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, `.items()` works in Py2, it just creates an intermediate `list` (where `viewitems` returns a cheap view, no shallow copy of key/value pairs). Of course, `sorted` makes a `list` internally, so in this case, `items()` doesn't hurt much, I just try to mention `viewitems` because it's better in most cases (and behaves exactly like `.items()` does in Py3).

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use `list` of `tuple` for your case:

```
 >>> replacement = [('2.48724e-008','6.1054382342e-10'), ('0.00022974','1.26357e-05'), ('0.0002':'1.1e-05'})]
 >>> for src, target in replacement:
     ... line = line.replace(src,target)
```

**Reason for the unexpected behavior of you code**:
`dict` in python do not store `{'key': 'value'}` pair in the order they are defined. So, order in which dictionary is defined and in which it is iterated using `dict.iteritems()` may change. Use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead for the cases where you want to maintain the order of the dictionary in which elements are entered. For example (based on your question):

```
>>> import collections
>>> sequence_list = [('2.48724e-008','6.1054382342e-10'),('0.00022974','1.26357e-05'), ('0.0002':'1.1e-05'})]
>>> replacement = collections.OrderedDict()
>>> for key, value in sequence_list:
    replacement[key] = value
```

Comment: You can't pass a `dict` to `OrderedDict` and get meaningful ordering; the construction of the `dict` lost the order, and `OrderedDict` will preserve that arbitrary order blindly. You'd need to pass a sequence of paired values, e.g. `collections.OrderedDict([('2.48724e-008', '6.1054382342e-10'), ...])` so `OrderedDict` receives them as you expect.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Updated the answer. Thanks for correcting me, I missed that part.

Comment: Cool. Down vote removed. `OrderedDict` isn't really necessary here (you could just iterate the `list` of `tuple`s directly after all), but it's no longer a bad answer.

Comment: I have added that answer as well. The reason I used `OrderedDict` over here was I wanted to let the OP know the root cause of issue. Else he would have never know why his program was not working as was expected